# I can't use any method inside subscribe method otto

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, event-bus, otto

My app show `fragment(1)`. After that user choose one of another `fragments(2-10)` for press `button`. After that, `fragment(2-10)` send data to activity and open activity  -that works well-. Finally, activity edit the data and send it to `fragment(1)` -here is problem- .

So I use otto. I use the same way except I didn't use `FragmentManager` class ,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVqBmGK3VuA  .Also I don't change anything in manifest and gradle except add compile of otto .

My problem is ,I can't use any methods inside subscribe method .Even I can't write

```
     message.getmsg()= my_varible
```

Answer (score 0):

Your message is not clear. What you want to do actually? 
are you not able to copy what he has shown in the video?

Comment: I did the same but I can't use any method inside subscribe method

Comment: I response to your question.I hope I can find answer